# what is the role assinged to the creater of the resource in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, rbac, azure-role-environment

We have a tenant where all users are provided contributor access. Now, if i create a resource, what is the role assigned to me?
I can see that whatever resource I create, I still inherit contributor role only. But ideally, I should get owner role for the resources I create!!
What am I missing here? Can you please route me to relevant document if any. I dont see the clear information on this.

Lets say, by default all users are given a very restrictive role -> 'reader' role for all the resources.
Now, user can have all sorts of role on the resources created by him.. so this works in azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a tenant where all users are provided contributor access. Now,
> if i create a resource, what is the role assigned to me?

You will get Contributor role. Because you did not explicitly assigned any role on the resource you created, you will inherit the role from the parent.

> But ideally, I should get owner role for the resources I create!! What
> am I missing here?

In order to get an owner role for the resource you crated, someone with owner or user access administrator role needs to grant you that role on the resource you created. You cannot grant yourself a higher role.

> Lets say, by default all users are given a very restrictive role ->
> 'reader' role for all the resources. Now, user can have all sorts of
> role on the resources created by him.. so this works in azure?

Explicit role assignment needs to be performed at the resource level.